# C : Can't understand how 2nd and 3rd method of declaration of structure and variables of this type are valid?

Tags: c

Here are three methods given in my book:-

1)

```
struct book
{   char name;
    float price;
    int pages;

};

struct book b1; b2; b3;

2)

  struct book
{
   char name;
   float price;
   int pages;
}  
  b1, b2, b3;   

3)

struct
{
  char name;
  float price;
  int pages;
} b1, b2, b3;
```

In 2nd method,there is a confusion why the closing brace in structure type declaration is not followed by a semicolon?

The 3rd method doesn't make any sense to me because we don't even declared the name of the structure.

So, How these two methods are valid?

Comment: a complete `struct` definition names a type, just like a simple `int` or `char` does. So it can be part of a normal variable declaration.

Comment: `struct book b1; b2; b3;` isn't valid C code anyway, so I'd toss that from the get-go. If your book really says that, contact the author, because it's wrong.

Comment: Structures can be anonymous, without names. And if you declare variables the way you do with "3" (and "2" for that matter) you don't need a name for the structure. Unless you want to use it later.

Comment: @WhozCraig I *guess* that's just a typo here ...

Comment: The answers are helpful but I would be grateful if somebody explains how '1' method is incorrect.

Comment: In method 1, the structure definition is OK. However the variable declaration should be `struct book b1, b2, b3;`. Notice the commas instead of semicolons after `b1` and `b2`. When you put a semicolon after `b1`, that ends the declaration. Which leaves `b2; b3;` with *"warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'"* So ironically, it's method 1 that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Oh my bad! It was me who posted struct book b1, b2, b3 as struct book b1; b2; b3; by mistake . So sorry for this! I realised this when I read book again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL/DR - C declaration syntax allows all three methods**.

Have patience, this is going to take a while.

Let's start with the syntax for a declaration:

```
declaration:
    declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt ;
    static_assert-declaration

declaration-specifiers:
    storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
    type-specifier          declaration-specifiersopt
    type-qualifier          declaration-specifiersopt
    function-specifier      declaration-specifiersopt
    alignment-specifier     declaration-specifiersopt

init-declarator-list:
    init-declarator
    init-declarator-list , init-declarator

init-declarator:
    declarator
    declarator = initializer
```

The `opt` subscript means that the item is optional; IOW, a sequence of declaration specifiers *may* be followed by a sequence of declarators (or not), a type specifier *may* be followed by more declaration specifiers (or not), etc.

We also have the following *constraint*:

> A declaration other than a static_assert declaration shall declare at least a declarator
> (other than the parameters of a function or the members of a structure or union), a tag, or
> the members of an enumeration.

<sub>*[C 2011 Online Draft, 6.7](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sub>

Lovely.  What does all that mean?

Basically, a declaration in C has two main parts - a sequence of *declaration specifiers* (which may include storage class specifiers like `static` and `auto`, type specifiers like `int`, `double`, `char`, `struct foo`, type qualifiers like `const`, etc.) and an optional sequence of *declarators* (basically, variable or function names), each of which may be initialized.  For example, in the declaration

```
static const int *foo[N] = { &bar, &blah, ... };
```

our *declaration specifiers* are `static const int`, our *declarator* is `*foo[N]`, and our *initializer* is `{ &bar, &blah, ... }`.

What we're interested in for the purpose of your question is the `type-specifier`, and specifically a `struct-or-union-specifier`:

```
type-specifier:
    void
    char
    short
    int
    long
    float
    double
    signed
    unsigned
    _Bool
    _Complex
    atomic-type-specifier
    struct-or-union-specifier
    enum-specifier
    typedef-name

struct-or-union-specifier:
    struct-or-union identifieropt { struct-declaration-list }
    struct-or-union identifier
```

The `struct-or-union-specifier` has two forms - one where you specify the contents of the struct, and one where you do not.

The `identifier` is the *tag name* of the structure or union; it's how you can refer to that specific type later on (either as part of another declaration, or part of a `sizeof` expression, etc).

Note that in the first case, where you're specifying the members of the structure type, the tag name is optional - it's perfectly legal to write a declaration like

```
struct { int a; int b; } x;
|                      | |
+---------+------------+ |
          |              V
          V          declarator
    type-specifier
```

The struct definition itself is a type specifier, just like `int` or `double`, etc.

However, without a tag name, you cannot refer to this same structure type in future declarations.  You can certainly repeat the definition for another variable:

```
struct { int a; int b; } y;
```

but the types of `x` and `y` will be *distinct* - the compiler considers each `struct` definition to be a different type, even though they have the same contents.

Now, remember from the general declaration syntax above, the list of declarators in a declaration is *optional*.  This is what allows us to declare a structure with just a tag name (although per the constraint above, you *must* include the tag name if you are not declaring a variable of this type):

```
struct foo { int a; int b; };
|                          |
+-----------+--------------+
            |
            V
      type-specifier
```

We've defined the struct type and given it the tag name `foo`; we can declare objects of this type as

```
struct foo x;
struct foo y;
```

Because from the syntax above:

```
struct foo x;
|        |
+---+----+
    |
    V
type-specifier
```

This time, `x` and `y` are considered to be the same type.

We can also declare a variable at the same time we define the struct:

```
struct foo { int a; int b; } x;
|                          |
+----------+---------------+
           |
           V
     type-specifier
```

struct foo y;
|        |
+----+---+
     |
     V
*type-specifier*

The first declaration creates the `struct foo` type and declares `x` to be a variable of that type.  The second declaration uses the previously defined `struct foo` type to declare a variable `y`.

Basically, C declaration syntax, especially with respect to structures, unions, and enums, is fairly flexible, and all of the methods listed in your book are equally valid.

Answer (score 2):

At the time a `struct` is defined, you can also define one or more instances of that struct.  This is what is happening in both the 2nd and the 3rd examples.

The difference between the two is that one declares three variables of type `struct book` at the time that type is defined, while the other declares three variables whose type is an anonymous struct.  In the latter case, that means that no other variables of that type may be defined since the struct has no name and does not have an associated `typedef`.

Comment: "*no other variables of that type may be defined*" doesn't matter too much in practice, because writing the same `struct  {...}` twice creates compatible types. But of course, you wouldn't do that anyways...

Comment: @FelixPalmen The only way you'd actually be able to use those types if a typedef was created at the time the struct is defined.  Otherwise, there's no way for two such structs to reference each other.

Comment: writing the same `struct` again still creates a compatible type. Yes, you can't have the **same** type, but you can sure use e.g. [pointers](https://ideone.com/bxDlrK).

Answer (score 2):

The whole construct of

```
struct {
    int field1;
    char field2;
    // ...
}
```

is itself a **type**. So you can use it in variable declarations in the same way you use other types. They are all of the form

```
<type> <identifier>;
```

with optionally more identifiers to declare multiple variables at once.

By example:

```
struct {int x; char y;} bar;
```

is a valid variable declaration, just as

```
int bar;
```

is. Remember newlines don't have any syntactical meaning in C.

---

With a `struct`, you can give it a name (called *struct tag*), like this:

```
struct foo {
    int field1;
    char field2;
    // ...
};
```

If you do this, you can later use the same struct type by just writing

```
struct foo
```

instead of repeating all its fields. That's in fact the most common usage.